# How to proper split line of data - ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python-3.x

I`m trying to parse edl (editing decision list) to get some value and pack it to csv file. After build automatic filter and some other user filter metod i have problem with some edls.

This is unfiltered edl:

```
**num, name, v, c, dur,  SourceIN, SourceOUT, RecordIN, RecordOUT**
```

```
016  AX       V     C        00:00:10:08 00:00:12:11 00:00:28:19 00:00:30:22
* FROM CLIP NAME: 00067.MTS

017  AX       V     C        00:00:01:04 00:00:02:24 00:00:30:22 00:00:32:17
* FROM CLIP NAME: 00097.MTS

018  AX       V     C        00:00:02:24 00:00:02:24 00:00:32:17 00:00:32:17
FCM: NON-DROP FRAME
018  AX       V     D    025 00:00:15:22 00:00:14:10 00:00:32:17 00:00:34:04
EFFECTS NAME IS CROSS DISSOLVE
* FROM CLIP NAME: 00097.MTS
* TO CLIP NAME: 00097.MTS
M2   AX       025.0                      00:00:02:24 
M2   AX       -25.0                      00:00:15:22 

019  AX       V     C        00:00:14:10 00:00:14:10 00:00:34:04 00:00:34:04
```

This is what myfiltered edl look like:

```
**num, name, v, c, dur,  SourceIN, SourceOUT, RecordIN, RecordOUT**
```

```
016  AX       V     C        00:00:10:08 00:00:12:11 00:00:28:19 00:00:30:22
017  AX       V     C        00:00:01:04 00:00:02:24 00:00:30:22 00:00:32:17
018  AX       V     C        00:00:02:24 00:00:02:24 00:00:32:17 00:00:32:17
018  AX       V     D    025 00:00:15:22 00:00:14:10 00:00:32:17 00:00:34:04
019  AX       V     C        00:00:14:10 00:00:14:10 00:00:34:04 00:00:34:04
```

I`m trying to split this line of information to:
num, name, v, c, dur,  SourceIN, SourceOUT, RecordIN, RecordOUT.
"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 8)"

I know that when remove 5 column which is "dur" program execute and stop on second 018 because there is value 025.
But when want all column program does not start because on first index on that column is no information till second 018.

My question is how to split the data to get all 9 column of data.
Thanks,
Maciek

````
            num, name, v, c,  SourceIN, SourceOUT, RecordIN, RecordOUT= a.split()
            print('{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},'.format(num, name, v, c,dur,  SourceIN, SourceOUT, RecordIN, RecordOUT))```
````

Comment: From the filtered example you show, you only have 9 columns of data on just one line.

Comment: Yes you are right. That is the case. How to split the line to have for example 0 in the linie which does not have information and get information from line where it is something like 025.

Comment: Does the data have fixed length? If so you could use "slices" to set your variables.

Comment: It does not. First column is index so can be max 4 digit - i think, name can be to 128, v and c can be 3.

Comment: Maybe I should change question. How to drop every line there on position c[3] is value different than 'C'. If value is different than 'C' that produce value on dur[4]. Column c[3] is ( C - cut, D-dissolve, W001,W002... - wipe information). How to iterate?